# Official bitcoin client fails to start with: Error initializing settings: Failed saving settings file:

Tags: usb, permissions, hard-drive, bitcoin

I want to run a full bitcoin node on ubuntu focal.
I was out of disk space so I bought a brand new 4TB USB hard drive for this.

I've formatted it as ext4 using the "disks" GUI.

It mounts correctly and my user can read/write files onto it.

But the [bitcoin client](https://bitcoin.org/) as installed by apt-get fails to start, failing to write its config file.

It gives the following error:

```
Error initializing settings: Failed saving settings file:
- Error: Unable to open settings file /mnt/bigdata/crypto/bitcoin/settings.json.tmp for writing
```

Here's the relevant part of /etc/fstab:

```
/dev/disk/by-id/usb-TOSHIBA_External_USB_3.0_20200917019302F-0:0-part1 /mnt/bigdata auto x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

I've tried creating the file manually:

```
touch /mnt/bigdata/crypto/bitcoin/settings.json.tmp
```

No issue and same error.

I've tried with other filesystems, same result.

I cannot try to run bitcoin in another directory as I literally have no space left on my other devices and I don't wanna move things to the USB drive to make room if I end up formatting it again for some reason.

I'm at loss here. Haven't touched linux in a while so excuse me if it's obvious.

I've attached a screenshot that sums up most of the information I have graphically.

[image: the error message and some relevant config]

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4):

If you installed from snap, just type in terminal :

```
snap connect bitcoin-core:removable-media
```

Comment: I had to dig and do so much troubleshooting before finding this instant fix.

Answer (score 0):

can you try running the bitcoin command as sudo, and if that doesnt work, can you try making the file writable with this command, possibly? `sudo chmod 775 file name here`

note that chmod 755 gives read & execute access to everyone, and write access to the owner.

Comment: tried both suggestions, same error.